# Use TEST to check if multiple bits of AL are all zero or all one

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to check that bits 0, 3, 6, 7 of `AL` are all **1** or not with `TEST` instruction.

I know I can check bit 0 with this code:

```
TEST AL,1
```

But how can I check bits 0, 3, 6, 7 together?

Comment: If you need to know if _all_ of those bits are set you need `AND` followed by `CMP`. `TEST` could be used if you want to check if _at least one_ of those bits are set.

Comment: @Michael: You can also `not al` / `test al, xxx` / `jz` to check that all those bits are zero after you invert them.  (Saves a byte of code-size for registers other than `al`, because `not` doesn't need an immediate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title is asking the opposite question from the body.  For a single bit, it's nearly identical (`test al,1<<bit_position` / `jz` or `jnz`).  But they're really different problems when you need to test multiple bits.

To check for **all zero**, it's still easy, because `test` sets ZF when the result of the AND operation is 0.  So mask the bits you want to look at, and check ZF.  Remember that you can `jz` or `jnz`, or `setz/nz al`, or `cmovz/nz ecx, edx`.

```
test  al, mask
jz   all_bits_selected_by_mask_were_zero
;; fall through path: at least one non-zero bit
```

To check for **all one**, the usual idiom is `x & mask == mask`.  This isn't ideal in asm, especially with an immediate constant, because you need the constant twice for `and` and `cmp`.  The other way is to invert all the bits and then check for zero using the previous way.  (This saves code bytes for registers *other* than AL, but there are special 2-byte encodings for most instructions with `op al, imm8`)

```
not   al
test  al, mask
jz   all_bits_selected_by_mask_were_one
;; fall through path: at least one unset bit


;;; or if mask has only a single bit set:
test  al, single_bit_mask
jnz  the_bit_was_set
```

Another optimization: if you need to test some bits that are all in the 2nd byte of EAX, it saves code bytes to read `ah`, but [this adds a cycle of latency on Haswell/Skylake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660139/how-exactly-do-partial-registers-on-haswell-skylake-perform-writing-al-seems-to).
e.g. `test eax, 3<<8` vs. `test ah, 3`.

For a single bit, `bt eax, 11` tests bit 11 (setting/clearing CF, so you can do fun stuff like `adc edx, 0` if you want to take that bit and add it somewhere else.)  But `bt` can't macro-fuse with JCC, so `test eax, imm32` is more efficient.

---

**In either case, the mask is `1<<0 |  1<<3 | 1<<6 | 1<<7`** for your case.  The number represented by a set bit in given position is `1<<n`, and assembler constants are specified in terms of numbers.

Of course, you can write constants in binary (using a `b` suffix in NASM for example), so you can do **`test al, 11001001b`**.